# SQL UPDATE based on COUNT

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update, aggregate

I have a table that looks as follows

```
ID   |   action   |  flag
1    |   A        |  1
1    |   A        |  1
1    |   B        |  1
2    |   A        |  1
2    |   A        |  1
2    |   B        |  1
2    |   B        |  1
```

I want to do the following: If for the same *ID* the value *B* in the *action* column appears more than *1 time*, then I want to set the *flag* column for this *ID* to *0*.

The result should look like this:

```
ID   |   action   |  flag
1    |   A        |  1
1    |   A        |  1
1    |   B        |  1
2    |   A        |  0
2    |   A        |  0
2    |   B        |  0
2    |   B        |  0
```

I know two ways to do this:

- Use a subquery: However, I don't want to use a subquery, because I deal with large tables, and a subquery deteriorates performance
- Use a temporary lookup table: I create a temporary lookup table, in which I store the *IDs* which have value *B* in the *action* colum more than *1 time*, and I then `join` the temporary table with the original table to find the *IDs* for which I will set *flag* to *0*

Is there another option besides the two explained above? Ideally in one query (without subquery and without temporary lookup table). I was thinking about something like a `JOIN` where the `JOIN` clause contains something like a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, but I wasn't successful until now..

Comment: For `ID=1` also, `A` is appearing more than once. Why need to update only for `ID=2`?

Comment: *"subquery deteriorates performance"* - this statement is not always true.....

Comment: because the condition is, that `B` should appear more than once.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, but it's definitely worse than creating a lookup table *once*, because the subquery needs to be executed once for each row.

Comment: @beta *"because the subquery needs to be executed once for each row."* - and this statement is not always true, for example subquery like `update t set.... where ID in (subquery)` (or queries in answers) will be executed only once for a whole query.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work for you:

```
UPDATE t
SET flag = 0
FROM Table t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Id
    FROM Table
    WHERE action = 'B'
    GROUP BY Id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) d ON t.Id = d.Id
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't this a subquery? does this have better performance than the temporary lookup table?

Comment: @beta Yes, it's a subquery, but it's not _correlated_ to anything.  Meaning, the database really only needs to execute it once.

Comment: It's called a derived table. since it's in the `from` clause, it will only execute once, as apposed to a sub query in the `set` clause, that will execute once for each row in the update.

Comment: okay, so the uncorrelated subquery is only executed once. but the `JOIN` could be extensive?

Comment: You mean expensive? Not if you have proper indexes.

Answer (score 3):

Doing an update join of your original table to a subquery which uses aggregation to identify candidate `ID` values is the fastest way which comes to mind:

```
UPDATE t1
SET flag = 0
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Note that this subquery is not correlated, meaning SQL Server will only execute it once for the entire `UPDATE`.  Therefore, it is not as big a penalty as you seemed to have imagined.

If you created a formal lookup table, you could in theory add indices to the join columns, and that might make the `UPDATE` faster.  But there is a hassle with creating *and* maintaining a lookup table.  In production, I would much rather have a single query used for updating.

Comment: how is this performance wise? is it better/equal/worse than creating a temporary lookup table beforehand? thanks. edit: thanks for the clarification about the subquery not being correlated.

Comment: 'COUNT(CASE WHEN action = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)' i think it will return same count even if 'B' not exists, bcs both '0' and '1' will consider as count.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed You're right...changed to `SUM()`, thanks